# fb: How to post on users profile when user signs up on the web app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook login in my app, evrything is working fine. I want two things now.

1. I want that whenever a new user comes, and clicks "login with facebook", after all process, a post should be posted on that users wall, that the user has started using my app with the link to app..
   Just like we see of that games, like "<user> started using Hold'em poker"
2. get users profile picture...

here is link to it http://oauth.netne.net/index.php

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

### For posting on user's wall:

Using Javascript:

```
    function doPost() {
    var params = {};
    params['message'] = "<USER> started using <YOUR APP NAME>";
    params['name'] = '<YOUR APP NAME>';
    params['description'] = '<DESCRIPTION ABOUT YOUR APP>';
    params['link'] = "<LINK TO YOUR WEBSITE>";
    //ON CLICKING THE POST WHERE YOU WANT USER  TO BE REDIRECTED e.g. www.yoursite.com
    params['picture'] = '<PATH OF PICTURE THAT YOU WANT TO BE DISPLAYED ON THE POST>';
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
        if(!response || response.error) {
            console.log('ERROR OCCURED '+response.error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('POSTED SUCCESSFULLY');
        }
    }}
```

Using PHP:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
       array( 'link' => '<LINK TO YOUR WEBSITE>',
              'message' => '<USER> started using <YOUR APP NAME>',
              'description' => "<DESCRIPTION ABOUT YOUR APP>")); //Returns the POST ID.
```

---

### For getting user's image:

`$fbImageUrl = https://graph.facebook.com/**<FBUSER_ID>**/picture?type=<VALUE>` (or)

`$fbImageUrl = https://graph.facebook.com/**<FBUSER_NAME>**/picture?type=<VALUE>`

Where  can be 'small' or 'normal' or 'large' or 'square'.

//For saving the image:

```
$localFilePath = 'pathToImagesFolder/<SOME_NAME>.jpg'; //Use relative path.
$fbImage = file_get_contents($fbImageUrl); //Fetches the image and stores it in variable.
file_put_contents($file1, $img1); //Will save the image in the path specified.
```

Comment: But I want to post to users profile only when they first time login that is when they sign up...

Comment: In that case you should be using PHP. Once User signs-up into your platform you are storing their details like `email-id` or `Fb_Userid` or `Fb_Uname` right? After login using Fb, Check if the user's `email-id` or `Fb_Uid` or `Fb_Uname` is already stored in your database. If user is signing-up in your platform for the 1st time post it on his/her wall. Else don't post it.

Comment: I have one problem 
here in this code $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email','user_hometown','user_birthday','user_about_me','user_location','publish_stream'));

publish_stream wasn't there, and now I have added it, and now it giving me error that user hasn't authorized to publish it...

Answer (score 0):

Yup U'll have to handle that condition. If user did not grant access Try this:

```
  try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
        array( 'link' => '<LINK TO YOUR WEBSITE>',
               'message' => '<USER> started using <YOUR APP NAME>',
               'description' => "<DESCRIPTION ABOUT YOUR APP>"));

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream'));
        header("Location: $login_url"); 
      }
```

But this will annoy the user if they are redirected continuously. So its better to just skip this step rather that forcing the user to accept it. Remember that you should provide all the scope that are required at the time of sign-up itself.